# Remove all characters after the last number

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

The values in my column is a combination of letters and digits, which looks like this: `abc1237pqr, 413ogty, ptw569q, qrt`.

How do I remove all the characters after the appearance of the last digit so that it becomes: `abc1237, 413, ptw569, qrt`? That is, the letters in the beginning are retained, but not the ones that appear after the digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `sub` to capture a digit (`(\\d)`) followed by one or more characters that are not a digit (`[^0-9]+`) until the end of the string (`$`) and replace with the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
sub("(\\d)[^0-9]+$", "\\1", df1$v1)
#[1] "abc1237" "413"     "ptw569"  "qrt"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(v1 =c('abc1237pqr', '413ogty', 'ptw569q', 'qrt'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```